# "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" when deploying sharepoint event receiver

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, exception

I have a simple event receiver, when I create a constructor I got the error in deployment step, I double checked the event receiver scope in feature, Elements.xml file and my code, the weird thing is when I remove the constructor(where I use service locator to get an instance of my implementation class) it works fine.

my code is something like this:

```
    private INotificationService iNotificationService;
    public CongeER()
    {
        SPSite currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
        IServiceLocator locator = SharePointServiceLocator.GetCurrent(currentSite);

        try
        {
            iNotificationService = locator.GetInstance<INotificationService>();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

   public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       iNotificationService.NotifyByMail();
       base.ItemAdded(properties);
   }
```

here is my stackTrace:

```
  Feature Activation: Threw an exception, attempting to roll back.
  Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 
  L'opération n'est pas valide en raison de l'état actuel de l'objet.     
  à Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionContentTypeAndEventReceiverBindings(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, Boolean fForce)     
  à Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionElements(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPWebApplication webapp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, Boolean fForce)     
  à Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, Boo...
```

Comment: Have you tried to activate the feature from the site user interface?

Comment: yes I did, the following occur:Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed.

Comment: This seems to be somehow a notification for a new Vacation. can you please tell the business scenario so I could offer you the solution that conforms to the best practices of SharePoint?

Comment: the business scenario is so simple: I need to send an email to the manager when a vacation request is sent from a web part or a web service, the class "iNotificationService" have various notification methods including sending an email.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use SharePoint Alert functionality and you do not need a workflow that can also send an email with minimum efforts you should remove the constructor and put its code into the ItemAdded method.

Comment: if I move the code from the constructor, the ItemAdded() function is called but I can't get a new instance from serviceLocator, thank's for your time.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: and the call stack? probably it is SPSite currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site; who is causing error during deployment from visual studio. try SPSite site = properties.OpenSite();

Comment: nope, now it is deploying correctly, I replaced SPSite currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site;  with SPSite currentSite = new SPSite("http://myAdress"); but iNotificationService.NotifyByMail(); is causing the error, however it is not null!

Comment: never mind I get it to work, the later problem was due to NotifyByMail() implementation error, you know it's end of the week, thank you so much sire.